# android animating views between pages

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-animation

I have been researching for the same since two days. Here is what i want to achieve. I havent ever tried much animations in android so please clear my approach wherever required. I will have two pages/screens (one visible at a time) Now when I am on page1, on swiping right to left page 2 will be displayed (achieving this is not that difficult) But here is my problem : when I am scrolling to page2 i would like to animate/translate/slide an image from page1 to page2 (without touching the image) and let the image sit on page2. I am just not sure of how to start with this. 
I have thought of few ideas

**First**: I think i should implement a layout larger then window and then do the required animations and scrolling in it using horizontal scrollview.But now here I am not sure how will I make it look like they are 2 different pages(concerned about handling different screen sizes)

**Second**:I have seen example libraries of draggable gridview viewpager. But here both of my pages will have different layouts

**Third**:I am thinking of dividing both of my pages. the lower part of my pages will contain framelayout where I will only change the framelayout's content on scroll and perform hide n show trick on the upper part.But here again the trick is how am I supposed to place the image(contained in framelayout) to upper layout with an animation(image sliding to the top side on its own kind of animation)

Any Ideas. Any views/suggestions. Need all of it.Thank You for your valuable time.

This happens when I am trying to move the image to screen's top-left position. It moves in the left top direction as shown in the images below..
[image: when app is launched image is at the center]
[image: the image is moving to the left top]

[image: finally moved to top-left]

This happens when I am trying to move it besides second fragment textview
[image: it moves to top right]

[image: finally placed here]

But the problem is I want to move it besides second fragment textview while scrolling and when scrolling is done it should come to top left of the screen just like the second fragment textview

Comment: @UmeshChhabra : Hav you also tried animating the image?

Comment: Yes i am changing fragments in view pager. And animating image according to page offset. Animating image down to up. I'll upload new age to server. My new comment will have links.

Comment: May I know how did you accomplished this?

Comment: http://bnconline.in/explorecity.in/photo/s1.png  ///   http://bnconline.in/explorecity.in/photo/s2.png ///// http://bnconline.in/explorecity.in/photo/s3.png /// http://bnconline.in/explorecity.in/photo/s4.png //////  http://bnconline.in/explorecity.in/photo/s5.png ///  http://bnconline.in/explorecity.in/photo/s6.png   ----/// I am using viewpager as 1st child of relative layout and imageview as 2nd child , so that image will be on the top, using fragments of different layouts . Using viewpager.onpagechangelistener to know how much is the offset of page and changing y position(y axis) of image.

Comment: I'll post code in evening if you want to see.

Comment: That is a great trick.. so you have positioned the image outside the viewpager? and using relative layout you placed it at top of the viewpager? right?

Comment: Yes!      &  Stack Overflow says you can not comment less than 15 characters :(

Comment: @UmeshChhabra: This trick works..:) I wanted to know how have you implemented the sliding animation? is it translation animation? I am using translation but what is happening is when I am done scrolling to next page the image goes back to its original position..

Comment: If you are animating using offset value, try to log offset value. It will become 0.0 at the end of scroll, that is the problem. Use if condition and do not animate at 0.0 value.

Comment: thats what I am doing.. I am using a condition where if offset > 0.01 then start animation.. but the animation now starts after the page is completely scrolled..

Comment: now I am encountered a new problem.. I am able change the position of the image.. But My animation isnt visible.. it changes the image's position quickly.. no matter what duration I set.. after I am done scrolling to second page.. the image quickly jumps to the position I have updated but doesnt animates..

Comment: Do not use animation, use imageView.setX(float); .setY(float); instead

Comment: even this is making the image jump to the given co-ordinates

Comment: You are giving co-ordinates of destination, dont do that. You have to make delta translation. Calculate the screen width, height( up/down translation in my case) . Move imageview some pixels( calculation based on offfset ) .

Comment: If you have time.. come on chat.. I will explain you what I exactly wish to achieve..

Comment: Ok, but i dont know how to chat on stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73638/discussion-between-pooja-gaikwad-and-umesh-chhabra).